# Download and Post file in one click for Embedded Software Updates using Javascript

Tags: javascript, post, embedded, raspberry-pi-pico

I have an embedded (Raspberry Pi Pico) system that can perform software updates by posting the new *.bin file via a USB web interface. At the moment this is done in three steps:

- User clicks a link to download the bin file from remote storage to their computer
- User browses for that file in a Post form
- User clicks Upload and that file gets sent to the Embedded system and update commences.

What I'd like to have happen is a single step:

- User clicks a link and bin file gets downloaded and posted to the embedded system.

Is there a way to do this? Perhaps using a Blob?

The above three steps all work and are summarized in the following code:

```js
// Download Latest Code
await fetch(`https://oursite.com/version.json`)
   .then(async (allData) => {
    console.log(allData);
    return await allData.json();
    })
    .then((version) => {
       // version numbers get filled in by embedded system 
       if ((version.majorVersion > 1) || (version.minorVersion != 0)) {
           versionDiv.innerHTML=`SOFTWARE UPDATE AVAILABLE: Latest Version is
             V${version.majorVersion}.${version.minorVersion}
             <div class="action-box">
                  <a class="action-button" href="${version.fileUrl}">Download BIN</a>
             </div>`;
       }
});

// User clicks Browse on webpage and selects Bin file, which then calls this function:
function uploadSoftware(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Make sure files are selected
    var thisFile = filesInput.files[0];

    // checks for file validity removed from here for clarity

    // Create the form object
    var uploadFormData = new FormData(uploadForm);

    // Initiate the AJAX request
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Ensure the request method is POST
    request.open('POST', uploadForm.action);    
    
    // Attach the progress event handler to the AJAX request
    request.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
        // show progress bar - works, removed for clarity
    };

    request.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            // Call the software update function on embedded system
            loadSW();
            uploadForm.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = `<div>File Transfer Successful,
                                                             Installing... </div>`;
        } else {
            uploadForm.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = `<div>Something went wrong!</div>  `;
        }
    };
    // Execute request
    request.send(uploadFormData);
    
};
```

I imagine there's a way to replace the fileUrl hyperlink with some Javascript that takes the data from the file at the fileUrl and stores it as a variable, to then use as thisFile in the next step, but not sure how to do it. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.